# UITableViewCells are not displayed on iOS 8 until device is rotated

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, ios8, ios-autolayout

I am using a UITableViewCell subclass with subviews and auto-layout which were displayed fine in iOS 7.x.

After upgrading my device to iOS 8 the cells are not displayed after the initial loading of the table view, but only after rotating the device (any direction will work). When I rotate back to the original orientation the cells are still there.
As soon as I add or delete a row or exit and enter the view again the cells are gone until the device is rotated again.

Please let me know if you need further details.

**UPDATE**:
Found the solution to my own question: make sure to return an explicit value in the following table view delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 44.f; //or whatever value is right for you
}
```

I returned `tableView.rowHeight` before which wouldn't work.

Comment: Hi, you question is not quiet clear. Can you please add snapshot of you story board and result you are getting.